# How to access fixture data in test case in CakePHP 2?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP 1.3 I used

```
$users = $this->_fixtures['app.user']->records;
```

Is there a way in Cake 2.x to get access to the fixture data in the test?

Answer (score 3):

You can access to the fixture data by loading fixture class.

This is a bother way but I don't know how to access fixture data directly because 
`$this->fixtureManager->_loaded` is declared as protected.

```
<?php
// register fixture path
App::build(array('Fixture' => array('%s' . 'Test' . DS . 'Fixture' . DS)), App::REGISTER);

// load fixture
App::uses('UserFixture', 'Fixture');

class UserTestCase extends CakeTestCake {
    public function testUser() {
        // access fixture data
        $userFixture = new UserFixture();
        $users = $userFixture->records;
    }
```